# How do I run a Makefile from a .pro-file?

Tags: qt, qt-creator, mapbox-gl

I added a git submodule to my project (at https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native).

It already has a Makefile and according to the project documentation at
https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/blob/master/platform/qt/README.md
I will need to run `make qt-lib` to compile the library.

In other words, I need to specify in the pro file in the including project that I have an already existing Makefile and want to run gnumake on it with a certain target.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe with a custom target: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-advanced-usage.html#adding-custom-targets

Something like

```
mapbox.target = mapbox/libmapbox.so
mapbox.commands = make mapbox/Makefile
```

Comment: Hm, seems like it is cmake I will use so I have a CMakeLists.txt file in the submodule directory, but is the executable of cmake like gnumake called "make"? And how will qt creator find the path of that command?

Comment: My custom target does not run and generates no error messages. I include it with QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS = mapboxgl and it is specified as mapboxgl.target = foo.obj mapboxgl.path = src/mapboxgl mapboxgl.commands = cmake qt-lib. I have no idea how qt would find the cmake command actually.

Comment: for cmake you need to steps, similar to using qmake:
1) run cmake to generate a Makefile, 2) run make on the Makefile.
You could potentially run (1) as a $$system() command in qmake, i.e. when qmake itself runs, and have the extra target for the make step